# Disable caching in django-views with imported json api

Tags: django, django-views

I have imported json from an api into my views. It now works perfectly fine but somehow if I go onto the website, somehow django is caching the values given by the api and therefore does not display the recent values. I've tried to use "never_cache" and "cache control" but it didn't work. Is there a solution I can do with django or Apache?

My views

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from urllib import urlopen
import json
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache, cache_control

response = json.loads(urlopen('http://api.fixer.io/latest').read())
usdollar = response['rates']['USD']

#@never_cache
@cache_control(max_age=0, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)
def home(request):
    return render(request, "index.html", {"usdollar":usdollar})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you are making your API call at module level. This means it will only run once, when the module is loaded. You should move the code into your view:

```
#@never_cache
@cache_control(max_age=0, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)
def home(request):
    response = json.loads(urlopen('http://api.fixer.io/latest').read())
    usdollar = response['rates']['USD']
    return render(request, "index.html", {"usdollar":usdollar})
```

Comment: This worked for me @Alasdair, cheers! Stragely `@never_cache()` (which should have the same effect as `@cache_control(max_age=0, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)` didn't work.

Comment: @P.Maino this answer was pointing out that `urlopen` call should be moved inside the view. The cache decorators are the same as in the original question. I’m not sure why `never_cache` didn’t work for you, but note it should be `@never_cache` without the `()`.

Comment: that's the crucial difference! cheers @Alasdair! `@never_cache` did work